# El conjunto de resultados no tiene fila actual

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Estoy haciendo un programa de `Libros` y `Autores` donde un `autor` tiene muchos `libros`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A la hora de insertar un nuevo `Libro` necesito obtener el `id` del `autor` para guardarlo como `fk_dni` en la tabla `Libros`, por lo que tengo el siguiente código el cual me carga un `combobox` con los `Autores` que están guardados en mi base de datos.

```
public void insertarLibro()
    {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Biblioteca";
        String user = "mi_usuario";
        String password = "mi_contraseña";
        String fk_dni = "SELECT dni FROM Autores WHERE nombre = '?'";


        try
        {
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(fk_dni);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            String nombre = (String)cboAutor.getSelectedItem();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                ps.setString(1, nombre);
            }

            System.out.println("DNI : " + rs.getString(1));
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR : ");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

    }
```

Pero mi programa devuelve el siguiente error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: El conjunto de
>   resultados no tiene fila actual

Por lo que deduzco que mi programa no esta entrando a mi bucle `while`. 
En caso de que yo elimine las comillas simples en mi consulta `fk_dni`, el error que me arroja es:

> El valor no está configurado para el número de parámetro 1.

El `System.out.println("DNI : " + rs.getString(1));` es temporal ya que solo lo utilizo para corroborar que el dato se muestra correctamente.

Comment: Adicional a lo indicado en las respuestas, cabe resaltar que sería mejor si buscaras el autor usando la llave foránea. Eso hace que la consulta sea **mucho** más rápida y asegura que obtengas 1 solo resultado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay algunos errores en el código:

- Consulta preparada mal escrita. El parámetro o los parámetros que serán pasados en el prepared statement, indicados por `?`  no deben ir rodeados de comillas simples como lo tienes ahora. Debería ser:

  ```
  String fk_dni = "SELECT dni FROM Autores WHERE nombre = ?";
  ```
- No puedes hacer el `executeQuery` antes de setear el parámetro `nombre`:

  ```
  try
  {
      String nombre = (String)cboAutor.getSelectedItem();
      Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
      PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(fk_dni);
      ps.setString(1, nombre);
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

      if(rs.next())
      {
         System.out.println("DNI : " + rs.getString(1));
      }

  }
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
      System.out.println("ERROR : ");
      e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
  ```

**Nota:** Buscar un DNI sólo por el nombre puede darte datos equivocados, puede que **José** el de Egipto no sea el mismo que **José** el de Nazaret.

---

- Contenido útil: Recomiendo el [Tutorial de Java sobre consultas preparadas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) (en inglés)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Convendría cambiar el `while` por un `if` puesto que debería obtenerse un solo resultado.

Answer (score 5):

Como ya dijo @A.Cedano, la consulta no lleva comillas simples en el signo de interrogación:

```
String fk_dni = "SELECT dni FROM Autores WHERE nombre = ?";
```

Además, tienes que pasarle el valor a la consulta y después ejecutarla

```
 public void insertarLibro()
    {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Biblioteca";
    String user = "mi_usuario";
    String password = "mi_contraseña";
    String fk_dni = "SELECT dni FROM Autores WHERE nombre = ?";


    try
    {
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(fk_dni);
        String nombre = (String)cboAutor.getSelectedItem();
        ps.setString(1, nombre);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
           System.out.println("DNI : " + rs.getString(1));
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR : ");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda Hernandez!